# Cannot run razor-page-intro sample project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

After I installed .Net Core preview 2 on my PC, I got the sample from Github at https://github.com/Rick-Anderson/razor-page-intro.

However, when I tried to run the sample using Visual studio 2017, I got the following error:

> *dependency conflict Microsoft.AspnetCore.All expected '2.0.0-preview2-25795' but received '2.0.0-preview2-final'*.

Could you please suggest some ways to resolve the above issue?
[image: Error]

Comment: I can't get it to run either. I tried upgrading to the 2.0.0 package at https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-release/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.0.0 and the restore was successfull, but it seems there are some breaking changes in the dotnet CLI that mess with the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource reference. See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to this:

I uninstalled my existing visual studio 2017, and reinstalled the latest preview version. After that the projects could be loaded and run.

Hope this helps someone.